# RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for [Enitity] was found when I using imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I started to use `typeorm` in my nodejs application (pure node, no nest).

And I also have a file with functions inside that using `typeorm`:

```
import {getRepository} from 'typeorm';
import { User, Post, ... } from './entities';

export const foo = () => { 
 const userRepository= getRepository(User);
 ... my logic ...
 user.find(...);
 ... my logic ...
}

export const bar = () => { 
 const userRepository= getRepository(User);
 const postRepository= getRepository(Post);
 ... my logic ...
 user.create(...);
 ... my logic ...
}

export const baz = () => { 
 const userRepository= getRepository(User);
 ... my logic ...
 user.delete(...);
}
```

I don't like when I have to call `getRepository` function in each function I write. I prefer to use `import` like that:

```
import { UserRepository, PostRepository, ... } from './repos';
```

the problem is I can't use `getRepository` before the connection was made. it throw me an error say:

```
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for [Enitity] was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
```

What I did is (repos.ts):

```
 export const UserRepository = getRepository(User);
 export const PostRepository = getRepository(Post);
```

because it have `export` the node/webpack try to resolve this variables first. before the application is running (and before the connection was made).

So any idea how to make it work as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is a pattern called Active Record.

`typeorm` have the option to use either Data Mapper (that you're using now, with `getRepository` or using Active Record that is `BaseEntity`.

For Active Record you can export them using export and import them without having this error.

For example:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity { ... }
User.findOne(..), User.find(..)
```

Data Mapper:

```
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {...}
const userRepository = connection.getRepository(User);
userRepository.findOne, userRepository.find(...)
```

Read more about [Active Record vs Data Mapper](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/active-record-data-mapper.md#what-is-the-active-record-pattern).

Answer (score -1):

On your ormconfig file, add entities object that has value that calls .ts, and .js format.

This is the example

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

dotenv.config();
const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: process.env.DB_SYNCHRONIZE === 'true',
  migrationsRun: !(process.env.DB_SYNCHRONIZE === 'true'),
  logging: true,
  logger: 'file',
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'migrations',
  },
};

export = config;
```